# escaped <code> format in stack overflow comments

Tags: format, comments

I'm new in stack overflow and i just tried to add comment to an answer with a code segment in it. The problem was that i couldn't insert a `<code> </code>` block. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) didn't help at all.

Is there any way we can put code formating in comments?

PS: Also a simpler way than 4 spaces before every line in answers would be great.

Christos Houtouridis

Comment: Sadly as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), the comments are using only a few features of markdown formatting. The only way to insert code is the inline code in backticks (`)

Answer (score 0):

Just put 4 spaces before each line in your code. You can use the wysiwyg editor and click in `{}` symbol to put that spaces for you.

```
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.someClass').each(function() { /* do something here */ });
</script>
```